# Assembly: test, cmp, and jne

Tags: assembly, x86

I have been stuck on trying to understand the following parts of assembly.

```
mov $0x11 %rcx
test %cl %cl
jne c
```

Suppose that %rcx holds a long. I know that `test` sets the ZF flag and `jne` checks that. However since `%cl` is used does that mean we are only checking whether the lower 8 bits of the long are cleared? In other words would the following code be a correct translation

```
long c = 17;
if (c < 256 && c != 0)
    goto c
```

(I used the condition `c < 256 && c != 0` because that is only time where the lower 8 bits are all 0). Any help will be really appreciated

Comment: Yes, it's only checking the low 8 bits. You got the code wrong though. For example think what happens with `513`.

Comment: Ok I see. Would this be a correct condition: if (c % (2^8) != 0) then go to c.

Comment: it'd just be `if ((char) c) goto c` to test if the lower 8 bits are non-zero.  Or `if (c & 0xff) goto c`

Comment: `2^8 == 0x100`, but `cl` is "masked out" low 8 bit part of `rcx`, i.e. `rcx & 0b1111_1111` (or `0xFF` or `255`). 2^n in binary is always just single "1" followed by n-1 zeroes (2^0 = 0b1, 2^5 = 0b10000), so the 2^n-1 is the full mask of lower bits. And `rcx` is 64 bits, not sure about your environment, but `long` is usually only 32 bits, so you probably meant `long long`, or rather use explicit `<cstdint>` types like `int64_t` or `uint64_t` to make it obvious, which one you meant.

Comment: Oh wait, you had `%` modulo there... ok, then 2^8 is correct idea, but in C or C++ syntax the `^` operator is `xor`, not power, so it's not clear which programming language you are using for that pseudo-code. But asm programmers rather use bit-wise operations like and/or/xor (`& | ^` operators in C and C++ and Java) to manipulate with bits, division and modulo are heavyweight operations used when you are outside of binary world, not needed for bits manipulation. So `(n % 256) == (n & 255)`, because that's how binary math works and 256 = 2**8 (but the `&255` is much cheaper operation for CPU).

Comment: `if (c % 256 != 0)` and `if (c & 0xff)` both work, but the latter could be a bit faster when the compiler fails to optimize the former. By the way, you used `c` both as a variable name and as a label, which is confusing.